# localizar índice onde um valor esta dentro do limite de dois valores do array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var current = 241;
var array = [ 
    { 
        start: 236.6,
        end: 239.42000000000002,
        value: 'hello word'
    },
    { 
        start: 239.42000000000002,
        end: 243.58,
        value: 'bar'
    },
    {
        start: 243.58,
        end: 246.12,
        value: 'X'
    }
]
```

O objetivo e localizar o índice do segundo item do array onde a variável `current` esta entre os valores `start` e `end` do array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu jSon não está formatado corretamente, existe erros de sintaxe.

Para que funcione utilize:

```
var array =[ 
    { 
        start: 236.6,
        end: 239.42000000000002,
        value: 'hello word'
    },
    { 
        start: 239.42000000000002,
        end: 243.58,
        value: 'bar'
    },
    {
        start: 243.58,
        end: 246.12,
        value: 'X'
    }
]
```

Respondendo sua pergunta... Para fazer um filtro, voce pode utilizar o seguinte comando: `var resultado = array.filter(l => l.start <= current && l.end >= current)`